# Angular выдает длинное число вместо lastmodified файла

Tags: typescript, angular

При добавлении файла в форму загрузки я хочу достать поле lastmidified , но вместо даты последнего изменения файла я получаю примерно следующее число :

```
1594298864031
```

но если в лог вывести полностью файл, то я получаю нормальную дату :

```
lastModified: 1597136924809, lastModifiedDate: Tue Aug 11 2020 12:08:44 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)
```

но поля  `lastModifiedDate` у файла нету :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно достать дату изменения файла ?

Comment: Это в милисекундах время 1597136924809

Comment: сделайте new Date(1597136924809) получите что надо

Comment: Спасибо,Aziz Umarov,вопрос решён !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это тип хранения данной информации. Не путайте с форматом вывода.

```
new Date(1597136924809)
```

Answer (score 2):

Это [Unix-время](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) в миллисекундах.